# The existence of a graph homomorphism

Tags: graph-theory

Is there a graph homomorphism between the 6-hypercube (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:6-cube_graph.svg) and the cube (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File:3-cube_graph.svg)?

Comment: The preposition "between" seems a bit confusing here -- an isomorphism is "between"; a homomorphism has a direction, which is more usually expressed by "from ... to".

Comment: Sorry, from the 6-hypercube to the 3-cube.

Answer (score 3):

A graph $G$ is bipartite if and only if there is a homomorphism from $G$ to $K_2$. So trivially there is a homomorphism from any cube to another. The interesting question for bipartite graphs is whether there is a surjective homomorphism from
one to another.

Edit: View the vertices of $(d+1)$-cube as binary vectors with length $d+1$.
Each vector can be written as $0u$ or $1u$ and the vectors of the form $0u$
form a subgraph isomorphic to $Q_d$. Consider the map that sends $0u$ to $u$
and $1u$ to $u+e_1$, where $e_1$ is the vector of length $d$ with first entry 1 and all other entries 0. Then this map is a surjective homomorphism from
$Q_{d+1}$ to $Q_d$.

Comment: I suspect that there exists a surjective homomorphism.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. For example, with $A=\{-1,1\}$, associate the vertices of the graphs with vectors in $A^6$ and $A^3$, respectively; then the function that maps $a\in A^6$ to $(\prod_ia_i,1,1)$ is a homomorphism.